# How can i change image author in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any function to change the image Author(Uploaded By) in WordPress library?

[image]

Comment: Here is your answer if you wanted to change it through code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186253/programatically-change-post-author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

```
$my_post = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_author' => $user_id,
);
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: I think it is for posts and pages not media attachments.

Comment: @Tarek This is working as well for attachments. Attachment are just another post type. Try it ;)